# Is a standards conforming C++ compiler allowed to optimize away branching on <= 0 for unsigned integers?

Tags: c++

Consider this code:

```
void foo(size_t value)
{
    if (value > 0) { ... }    // A

    if (value <= 0) { ... }   // B
}
```

Since an unsigned cannot be negative, could a standards conforming C++ compiler optimize away the B statement? Or would it just choose to compare to 0?

Comment: It can be zero, can't it?

Comment: It can, hence the question (added the clarification for just that while you added the comment :))

Comment: Standards **NEVER** define how compiler optimizes.

Comment: Rule of thumb: If you can't tell the difference (without examining the generated code) then the compiler conforms to the standard.

Comment: @texasbruce, What about RVO?

Comment: @texasbruce Actually, it does, by limiting the range of valid optimisations (see "as-if" rule).

Comment: @texasbruce: No, and that doesn't necessarily contradict anything I ask for. It just cannot violate the standard in doing the optimization. Hence, is it allowed do optimize it, and still be conformant? Is the "just compare with 0 instead" the only thing it'll do?

Comment: @chris It does not define it. It gives suggestions and does not enforce it.

Comment: @texasbruce, Oh, I misunderstood your statement then.

Comment: It certainly should not optimize away the branch since it is possible for the conditional to be true. Whether it optimizes the check to compare with only 0, that's a valid question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the code is correctly written, `B` cannot be optimized away, because `value` can be zero, though the particular comparison used can be replaced with an equivalent one as shown in Angew's answer. But if the statements in `B` invoke undefined behavior, all bets are off. For ease of reference, let's rewrite `foo` as

```
void foo(size_t value)
{
    if (value > 0) bar(); // A
    if (value <= 0) baz(); // B
}
```

If the compiler can determine that `baz()` invokes undefined behavior, then it can treat it as unreachable. From that, it can then deduce that `value > 0`, and optimize `foo` into

```
void foo(size_t value)
{
    bar();
}
```

Comment: Even if `baz()` invokes undefined behaviour, why would that imply `value > 0`?

Comment: @Pixelchemist Because the compiler can assume that that branch is unreachable, and therefore that the condition `value <= 0` is never true. Another way to think about it is that `value == 0` will invoke UB, and with UB the compiler can do anything, and "anything" includes "behave as if `value > 0` instead".

Comment: Actually, I wouldn't be surprised since the standard explicitly says that there is no requirement on the implementation executing the program (not even with regard to operations preceding the first undefined operation). Nevertheless, I'd appreciate a standard quote here.

Comment: Accepting this answer for now, for the mentioning of the UB case, which is a clear "yes" to the original question.

Comment: @Pixelchemist: The "no requirements even before UB" only applies if the combination of program and input eventually leads to UB. And the burden of proof is on the compiler. Still, consider `if (value <= 0) value = 5/value`. This whole statement can be optimized out: the only possible unsigned value (0) leads to UB.

Comment: @MSalters Well ok, but I'd like to read the part of a valid source where it says that this optimization not only optimizes out statement B but also removes the condition for the call to `bar()`. I got the idea that if the compiler figures out that "`value` cannot be `0` because it leads to UB it must be `> 0`".

Comment: @Pixelchemist I'm not sure what source you are looking for. If `baz()` invokes UB, then essentially the function is "if `value > 0`, then `bar()`; otherwise no requirements" (by your own quote), which can validly become "if `value > 0`, then `bar()`; otherwise `bar()`", which can validly become "`bar()`"

Comment: @T.C. The standard for example. If the function is `if value > 0 then bar(); otherwise no requirements` why should `no requirements` be replaced by `bar()`? I would expect the function -if altered at all- to be `if value > 0 then bar();`

Comment: @Pixelchemist If the standard imposes no requirements on the implementation, then why *can't* the compiler replace "no requirements" with `bar()`? The compiler doesn't have to replace it with `bar()`, but it is allowed to because there are *no requirements* on what it does.

Comment: @T.C. Your answer suggests that the optimization you describe is somehow "defined" behaviour for any implementation. Imho it wil be easier to understand if you emphasize that this is only one thing that *might* happen since there is no requirement around at all.

Comment: @Pixelchemist Where did I suggest it is "defined"? I said the compiler "can", not it "will" or "must".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72421/discussion-between-pixelchemist-and-t-c).

Answer (score 8):

Well, it clearly cannot optimise away the B statement altogether—the condition body does execute when `value` is 0.

Since `value` cannot, by any means, be `< 0`, the compiler can of course transform B into `if (value == 0) { ... }`. Furthermore, if it can prove (remember that the standard mandates strict aliasing rules!) that `value` is not changed by statement A, it can legally transform the entire function like this:

```
void foo(size_t value)
{
    if (value > 0) { ... }    // A
    else { ... }   // B
}
```

Or, if it happens to know that the target architecture likes `==` better, into this:

```
void foo(size_t value)
{
    if (value == 0) { ... }    // B
    else { ... }   // A
}
```

Comment: It can remove `B` - and the comparison in `A` too - if the statements in `B`'s block invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @T.C. Good point. I will incorporate it, but I have no more time today :-(

Answer (score 2):

Since the compound statement must be executed if the unsinged `value == 0`, a conforming compiler cannot optimize away `if (value <= 0) { /* ... */ }`.

An optimizing compiler will probably consider several things here:

1. Both statements are mutually exclusive
2. There is no code in between both of them.
3. `value` cannot be smaller than zero

There are several possible "outcomes" of this scenario where every scenario consists of one comparison and one conditional jump instruction.

I suspect `test R,R` to be "more optimal" than `cmp R, 0` but in general there is not much of a difference.

The resulting code can be (where Code A and Code B contain a ret):

**Using `cmp`**

```
 cmp <value>, 0
```

A)

```
 je equal
 // Code A
equal:
 // Code B
```

B)

```
 jne nequal
 // Code B
nequal:
 // Code A
```

C)

```
 jg great
 // Code B
great:
 // Code A
```

D)

```
 jbe smoe
 // Code A
smoe:
 // Code B
```

**Using `test`**

```
 test <value>, <value>
```

A)

```
 je equal
 // Code A
equal:
 // Code B
```

B)

```
 jne nequal
 // Code B
nequal:
 // Code A
```